# Chrome/Firefox Cutting off Base64 Image

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox, base64

I'm building a project in ASP/MVC, and I'm having an issue with some of my images. I pull them out of a database as bytecode, convert them into Base 64, then render them. This process works fine with about 90% of the images I have to upload, but for certain images for some reason, they render cut off, as here:

[image: Cut Off Logo]

Unfortunately, this only seems to happen in Chrome/Firefox, so I have to assume it's an issue with rendering. In fact, here's the image as the base 64, you can view it by using it like a url in your browser, if security allows. Otherwise you can put it in html tags and try to view it that way. This will only render correctly on IE as far as I can tell.

http://pastebin.com/RYasvfj0

If I view this image, right click, then save it, the saved image will be correct:

[image: Cut off logo 2 not cut off]

I'm at a total loss here. It's A) Inconsistent that the images won't work correctly, but
B) Consistent at when in the image it gets cut off. It's always the same portion through the image that it ceases loading on FF/Chrome

Any ideas on what's triggering those browsers to fail, and how I can check for it?

e; The base 64 here is padded; it's generated by C# via `Convert.ToBase64String`